# Chrome compiling problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

[Chrome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZs9M.png)[Firefox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkCPG.png)
So, I developed a website and it looks good on all browsers. But when I uploaded it to webserver, it looks different on google chrome. I tried to open my html project directly from computer via chrome and it looks ok.
Why G.Chrome compiling different on webserver when directly from computer it looks good.
Where can be a problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Chance are your paths aren't correct, or there is a security violation. Have you looked at the developer tools (f12)?

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be because most web browsers have pre assigned CSS rules. Perhaps google overrided your rules? I think you can fix this with the `!important` tag in your css file.
Example

```
body {

  background-color: blue !important;

  border-left: 2rem !important;

}
```

Comment: It even looks different in code when I open it in developer tools. In original index, there is a comment after </html> as my signature. If I look at it in developer tools it's before javascript <script> tags and it's wrong. Weird thing is that if I look at it directly from my computer via Google Chrome it looks fine. Can be problem on webhosting?